# Possible to get bash input while user is at prompt? (Essentially an event listener)

Tags: bash, events, readline

### Old stuff:

> Background:
>   - Ultimate goal is to put a script in my `.bash_profile` that warns me by changing text color if I'm typing a commit message and it gets too
>   long (yes I'm aware vim has something like this).
>
> Progress:
>   - I found the `read -n` option which led me to write this:
>
> ```
> while true; do
> # This hits at the 53rd character
> read -rn53 input
> # I have commit aliased to gc so the if is just checking if I'm writing a commit
> if [ "${input:0:2}" = "gc" ]; then
>     printf "\nMessage getting long"
> fi
> done
> ```
>
> Question:
>   - However, running this takes the user out of the bash prompt. I need a way to do something like this while at a normal prompt. I can't find
>   information on anything like this. Does that mean it's not possible?
>   Or am I just going about it the wrong way?

### New progress:

I found the `bind -x` option which led me to write this:

```
check_commit() {
    if [ "${READLINE_LINE:0:13}" == 'git commit -m' ] && [ ${#READLINE_LINE} -gt 87 ]; then
        echo "Commit is $((${#READLINE_LINE} - 87)) characters too long!"
    fi
    READLINE_LINE="$READLINE_LINE$1"
    READLINE_POINT=$(($READLINE_POINT+1))
}
bind -x '"\"": check_commit "\""'
```

It listens for a double quote and if I'm writing a long commit message tells me how many characters I am over the limit. Also puts the character I typed into the current line since it is eaten by the bind.

### New question:

Now I just need a way to put in a regex, character list or at least a variable instead of `\"` so I can listen on more keys (Yes, I'm aware `bind -x` probably wasn't intended to be used this way. I can check performance/footprint/stability myself). I tried `"$char"`, `"${char}"`, `"$(char)"` and a few other things, but none seem to work. What is the correct approach here ?

Comment: You won't be able to do anything to the parent bash program from a child process script, but you might be able to work on the `readline` by sourcing `.inputrc`.  Do a `man bash` and search for the `READLINE` title.

Comment: @cdarke Thanks. Updated post. I found `bind -x keyseq:shell-command` and have it working. Now I just need to bind to a list of characters or at least a variable. Do you know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, not possible in a sane way if you want this to happen during your normal prompt (when `PROMPT_COMMAND` and `PS1` are evaluated).  That would involved binding a custom compiled readline function for every `insert-self` and alike.

If you want this to happen in a script using `prompt` builtin, this is crudely possible with a loop of

```
read -e -i $(munge_buf $buf) -n $(buf_warn_len $buf) -p $(buf_warning $buf) buf
```

like commands. This will allow you to create `munge_buf()` to alter the currently typed text if needed, `buf_warn_len()` to calculate a new len to warn at (which may be very large if warning was already displayed), and `buf_warn_msg()` to derive a warning message based upon the buffer.

Comment: I want to run in the normal terminal so I am trying with `readline`, see updated post. Any advice appreciated.